# C# Pause/Stop System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#, process

I have a Process that runs an exe:

```
Process pr = new Process();                                                 
pr.StartInfo.FileName = @"wput.exe";
```

etc

I want to be able to pause and stop this Process.  Are there any events I can raise to achieve this.  I have multiple Processes working in my app, each with it's own Thread.  I looked at pausing Threads but that would not give me the result I want.

Comment: Some people said that you cannot pause a process when it has started.  However, I can pause the cmd program using the Pause|Break key on my keyboard.  Is there no way to send that command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read the list of processes in the system, as task manager does and try to kill the process with the name "wput.exe".

Try this

```
using System.Diagnostics;


private void KillAllProcesses( string name )
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName( name );
    foreach( Process p in processes )
        p.Kill();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To kill just started process use:

```
pr.Kill();

pr.WaitForExit();
// now you sure that it has been terminated
```